# Typescript: void union type

Tags: typescript

What is the purpose of void as a union type compared to a optional parameter, can they be used interchangeably? I was expecting `example.func1();` to throw an error in the following example:

```
interface IExample
{
    num: number;
}

class Example implements IExample{
    num = 1;
    public func1(param: IExample | void){
    }

    public func2(param?: IExample){
    }
}

var example = new Example();
example.func1(); // no error - error expected
example.func2(); // no error
example.func1(example); // no error
example.func2(example); // no error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFEAecC2AHAGwgCgBvY5S5EAVxwC5q6AjaAbmIF9jiEC4AzgORZchFMHxEcEcMIzYpEclSY5kAXmQBGDqrw1mBYAmQwaIBNoAUeOFFyMFYosgA+yAG4B7YABMAShUqbgoqAyMTMwsEACZbe1wAfidRJSCwym5Qz3tkCEVxTWoIAHcRQqJrAI4ClwgAOnNLGxriOqUmmPi2jvEulus+ol7Kxua4obGaoA)

Comment: There are a few things going on here. You have an empty `interface`. Most linters will warn you about declaring types with no members because almost everything is a subtype of `{}` including `{}`, `1`, `{p: number}`, `["x", 3]`, `() => {}`, etc. The last 2 calls, are valid because `() => Example` is a subtype of `IExample`. I'm perplexed by the first two calls because `function f(x: {} | undefined)` does not render `x` optional, just allows you to pass `undefined`. I feel like there is something obvious I am missing...

Comment: @AluanHaddad 100% with you on empty interfaces, I made it empty for this example only. `example.func1();` is the reason that I made this post, because I don't understand why this is not an error. I am in the same boat re missing something super obvious.

Comment: Interestingly, the following _is_ an error: `type T = {p: string | void}; let x: T = {}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to ignore the empty interface issue whereby any non-nullish values are compatible with `{}`.  Add members to your interface and the `() => example` calls will fail.

---

I don't think this is really documented anywhere obvious, but in TypeScript **trailing function arguments that accept `void` are considered optional**, a feature implemented in  [microsoft/TypeScript#27522](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27522).  So your two functions behave similarly.

```
declare let f1: (x?: string) => string;
declare let f2: (x: string | void) => string;
f1(); // okay
f2(); // okay
```

There's some weirdness surrounding this feature, such as the fact that it doesn't work in the face of generics ([microsoft/TypeScript#29131](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29131) and [microsoft/TypeScript#39600](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39600)).

And the compiler doesn't see the types of `f1` and `f2` above as truly interchangeable, despite being callable in the same ways:

```
f1 = f2; // okay
f2 = f1; // error!
```

probably because `void` is also a type given to return values from functions where you're not supposed to use the return value, leading to this bizarre situation:

```
f1(console.log()); // error
f2(console.log()); // okay?!
```

And the feature only applies to function parameters; object properties that accept `void` are *not* considered optional (although it's been even [suggested](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195#issuecomment-325525572)  and implemented but not (yet?) merged in [microsoft/TypeScript#40823](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40823)).

So I'd say it's kind of a limited-scope not-fully-general not-fully-baked not-well-documented feature you've stumbled into.  Oh well, hope that makes some sense.  Good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABFMAXRAzAjALkQCgA8B+PAZ1TgEsA7AcwEpEBeAPkQuvoG5RJYEyNJgBMeIuUq06iAD6IAbgHsqIJmw5SewbPgbdEAekOIlAaxgBPHSL0Hjpi9Z1Z8EJTTJKUAOihK6PX0jEzA4OCU4GzcPL19-QIZgh3MrYgBCYBcWUXsTVOsMERzsPMQwiLh0oA)

Comment: Thanks jcalz - this is really good. I have also updated my question now with a better defined interface to mitigate the identified issue.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation and the context here. Would be fair to say that one should prefer `x:? T` over `x: T | void` to denote optional parameters wherever possible for the preservation of sanity and love of common decency?

Comment: Yeah, given the state of the feature, I'd recommend staying clear of it.