# difference between `unknown` and `void`

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58885486):

> Using `void` instead means that forEach promises not to use the return value, so it can be called with a callback that returns any value

According to the [TypeScript 3.0 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type)

> ... `unknown` is the type-safe counterpart of `any`. Anything is assignable to `unknown`, but `unknown` isn’t assignable to anything but itself and `any` ...

As much as I think about this, from these descriptions I can't find any single difference between those types.

I have also noticed that unlike `unknown`, when `void` is used as a type of a function argument, that argument can be omitted when calling the function, even though it is not marked as optional:

```js
declare const x: (a: void) => void

x()
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gDwFzwAop8A3JAS2AEp4BeAPnjMoCgXsCqWg)

While this behaviour is sometimes useful when working with generic code, it seems very strange. If `void` is supposed to only ever be used in return types, why does it have this special behaviour, unlike every other type?

Answer (score 15):

After a lengthy discussion with Aluan Haddad, my understanding is the following:

`unknown` is a supertype of every other type. in other languages, this is mostly what the `void` type is - anything can be assigned to it, but it can be used for nothing.

`void` is a special type. under normal circumstances, it is only a supertype of undefined and no other type, not even `null`.

This is what allows us to do any of the following:

```
const x: void = undefined;

(): void => undefined;

(): void => {};
```

but prevents us from doing any of:

```
const x: void = null;

const y: void = 5;

(): void => 5;
```

Unlike other types, though. `void` has a special behaviour if used in an output position (as part of the return type): `() => T` is a subtype of `() => void` for any `T`, which includes `undefined`, `null` and of course `void`.

This enables doing things like:

```
const x: () => void = () => 5
```

the reason for `void` existing and being used seems to be more historical than practical, given that it has existed before `unknown` and that it interacts with the type-system differently than all other types (which also causes some weird things, like `Promise<number>` not being a subtype of `Promise<void>`).

The common way to decide between these types seems to be:

- Is it a return type of a function which I only call for side effects? Use `void`.
- Is it a type (return or not) which I intend to utilise somehow, but have no guarantees about? Use `unknown`.

Comment: Yeah, this looks right to me.  The other "weird" behavior of `void` which makes them optional in function parameters was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#27522](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27522) but there have been bugs raised at [microsoft/TypeScript#29131](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29131) and [microsoft/TypeScript#39600](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39600).  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63349111/typescript-void-union-type) for more info

Answer (score 2):

The short version is that using a function that returns void, the caller must disregard it.

It's different `unknown` because `unknown` does not explicitly mean 'don't use this', it simply means that it could be anything.