# Typescript: Void vs Any when defining a function in an interface

Tags: typescript, function, methods, interface

I have been trying to document and set up a type definition for an API that I have to work with and discovered the ability to set a function as a property in the interface. While researching the correct way to do this, I came across [this article by Jeff Butsch](https://medium.com/@jeffbutsch/typescript-interface-functions-c691a108e3f1) that states,

> Example 1: Function that does not take arguments and does not return a
> value: In the example belowonChange is the function declaration. The
> function returns nothing (void) so we declare the return type as any.
> This is because void and never are evaluated differently in different
> contexts (beyond the scope of this article). (Below are some examples
> of typed return values.)
>
> ```
> interface MyClassProps {
>     someProp: string;
>     onChange(): any; } class MyClass extends React.Component<MyClassProps, MyClassState> ...
> ```

I have not been able to locate any other references to how Typescript would handle `void` in a method declaration in a way that would produce unexpected results and make it worth declaring `any` instead.  (Searches for things like 'typescript interface method declaration void any never'  return a lot of irrelevant results as those keywords appear with each other in a wide variety of contexts.)

Can anyone offer any insight as to the actual difference here? What problems could potentially be encountered from declaring a method in an `interface` as returning `void` when one legitimately expects it to return `void`?

Comment: If the return type is `any` then a caller can use the return value in completely unsafe ways with no compiler errors (like `myClassProps.onChange().toUpperCase()`). If the return type is `void` then someone who calls the function cannot use the return value at all without error, except for possibly assigning it to a value of type `void`.  The return type `void` means "don't try to use the return value from this function".  I honestly couldn't say why the article author prefers the unsafe version, and the fact that it's "beyond the scope of this article" doesn't give much to go on.

Comment: That was my understanding of it, I was mainly wondering if there actually was a good reason for using `any` when you really mean `void` specifically inside an `interface` declaration.

Comment: There are definitely some "weird" behaviors with `void` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65721318/why-is-return-type-null-or-any-other-type-assignable-to-return-type-void) for example) but I wouldn't know why someone would prefer to use `any`, which is arguably "weirder" since it turns off all type checking.  So, uh, how could this question get an authoritative answer?  I don't know "why one might want to incorrectly declare `any`" other than baseless speculation, which isn't generally appropriate in an SO answer.

Comment: It could receive an authoritative answer if someone has a good explanation for what problems the blogger, or a programmer in general, might anticipate by assigning `void` in an interface method. I read it as also having something to do with evaluation of `never` but I might have read that wrong. I'll clarify my wording on the final question.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66190346/difference-between-unknown-and-void) shed any light on that?  It talks about `unknown` instead of `any`, which is at least a *safe* alternative to `void`.

Comment: I didn't know about `unknown` so that was interesting. Still hasn't offered any explanation of a negative side effect that could make someone want to avoid listing a return type as `void`. Maybe the blog I read to begin with was simply incorrect.

Comment: You may read a pretty argumented critique of using the `void` type here [microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42709](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42709). But that's really advanced usage and still doesn't justify using `any` over it.