# Why is undefined assignable to void?

Tags: typescript

In the documentation on the typescript it is written that: "the one exception being that undefined is also assignable to void".

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks

> In strict null checking mode, the null and undefined values are not in the domain of every type and are only assignable to themselves and any (the one exception being that undefined is also assignable to void). So, whereas T and T | undefined are considered synonymous in regular type checking mode (because undefined is considered a subtype of any T), they are different types in strict type checking mode, and only T | undefined permits undefined values. The same is true for the relationship of T to T | null.

Why is this exception made for void?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885485/why-does-typescript-have-both-void-and-undefined) is not an answer. Please do not offer

Comment: Can you [edit] this question to distinguish it more clearly from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885485/why-does-typescript-have-both-void-and-undefined ?  Otherwise this one might be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: jcalz, I edited the question

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of text with the actual plain text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: I replaced the image with text. Thanks

Comment: From looking at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25481 it seems that `undefined` is assignable to `void` so that `return;` and `return undefined;` are allowed inside functions with a `void` return type.  Does that answer your question or are you looking for something else?

Comment: There's also [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65721318/why-is-return-type-null-or-any-other-type-assignable-to-return-type-void) which goes over some of the weirdnesses of `void`

Comment: "it seems that undefined is assignable to void so that return; and return undefined; are allowed inside functions with a void return type"

Yes, that's the answer. Thanks. And thank you for the additional link too.

Comment: Okay I will write it up when I get a chance.

Comment: When you have a void function, it returns nothing. When a function returns nothing, its return value is undefined. This is the behavior of javascript which you can't remove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relationship between `void` and `undefined` is a little muddy because there are a a few mutually inconsistent ways they are used.  To a first approximation, `void` is meant to be the return type of a function that doesn't return a meaningful value. But it gets sticky when you start picking that apart.

---

From the point of view of a *caller* of a `void`-returning function, it means that it is essentially an error to do much of anything with the return value:

```
declare let voidReturn: () => void;

let v = voidReturn();
v.foo; // Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'void'
v + 2; // Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'void' and 'number
```

Since callers essentially promise not to inspect the return value of a `void`-returning function, it is safe to assign any function in its place, whether it returns a value or not:

```
voidReturn = () => 123; // okay
```

See [the handbook documentation about returning `void`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#return-type-void) for reasoning why that is allowed.

Anyway, from this point of view, you're not really supposed to look at `undefined` being particularly assignable to `void`.  You can't really use a `void` return value as if it were `undefined` (since it might well be `123` as you see), and type checking function types treat almost anything as assignable to `void` in the sense that `() => T` is assignable to `() => void` for all `T`.

From the point of view of callers of `void`-returning functions, it's as if `void` is like [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown).  But `void` predates `unknown` by quite a bit.

---

On the other hand, from the point of view of an *implementer* of a `void`-returning function, the compiler takes the position that returning any defined value is a mistake:

```
function voidReturn2(): void {
  return 123; // error!
  // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'void'.(2322)
}
```

That's almost the same as the `voidReturn = () => 123` assigned function expression, but this one is considered an error.  Yes, this is technically inconsistent.  Using an existing thing-returning callback function in a place that wants a `void`-returning function is useful and happens all the time, as described in the above handbook doc.  But directly returning a defined value where a `void` value is expected is less useful and more indicative of an error.

Anyway, it means that you should not return anything when implementing a `void` returning function:

```
function voidReturn3(): void { } // okay
```

A function without a return statement is equivalent to one that ends with just `return;`.  So the compiler should probably accept that also, and it does:

```
function voidReturn4(): void {
  return;
} // okay
```

A function that does not specify a value after `return` is equivalent to one that returns `undefined`.  So the compiler should maybe accept that also, and it does:

```
function voidReturn5(): void {
  return undefined;
} // okay
```

And *that* is why `undefined` is assignable to `void`.  When you have an expression that's supposed to be of type `void`, the only acceptable value to put there is `undefined`.

---

Of course it's not really consistent and leads to some strange behavior that is maybe undesirable.  Callers of `void` returning functions should ignore their return value.  But they don't have to, and then they might have a variable of type `void` hanging around.  And you can assign `undefined` to it but not `123`:

```
let w = voidReturn();
w = 123; // error
w = undefined; // okay, but that's weird
```

Oh well.

You can also look at [microsoft/TypeScript#25481](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25481) and other Stack Overflow questions about the strange behavior of `void` such as [Why does TypeScript have both `void` and `undefined`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885485/why-does-typescript-have-both-void-and-undefined) or [why is return type `null` (or any other type) assignable to return type `void`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65721318/why-is-return-type-null-or-any-other-type-assignable-to-return-type-void) or [Typescript: void union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63349111/typescript-void-union-type).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEEQBd4DcD2BLYAlFArjAHYBc8AFAJTwC8AfOtsANwBQbSqadTO+yIsWrs0AOgBmGDC3gB6OfAAKMDAAcQMZAE94AcikY98YBhABneMQyoQADyznUGYvB0b9mHHrY8A1PAATLIK8ADyGjBQyBgw+n7GYFDE1qgARghQamoQWCDAbhhu2hqWel7AxskFesQEALYZMBxsYC5O8FDkBMSgEljE+bxoIYqaqs2+zAJCvNR0jACMgQDMo-AYANZQ2hwSPWDIWC58eIQkgdTkFfAA3mzw8HCCJPDLa-JjMBMAhA+f8AAKiUELUGk1jI4rDZOuZzFgAObEKBpJCFYoecrMPRiCirQKBKhsAC+LX2xEOx1cFRmJBWV1Od3gxIBWx2ewORxONPOxAALAybvdHs8hOwWaE2bs2OTKdzpryAKyC5h3f6i149PoDfLi1nbaVceAAd2GCpewio7FNtDeq3W41ibBt8C1IH6g1Y+p2ABp4GkCKhkAALaJ6SzGkBYGDANhAA)