# How to use void and number type in functions with guard-clauses

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

Problem: I'm trying to write a simple function with a guard-clause in addition to returning a value with type: `number`, but ESLint is telling me "void is only valid as a return type or generic type variable"

P.S: I don't know why ESLint is throwing me this, if I use void as a return type for guard-clause ...

Code:

```js
function addTwoNumbers(one: number, two: number): void | number {
  if (one < 0 || two < 0) return;
  return one + two;
}

const result = addTwoNumbers(-5, -5);
console.log(result);
```

I've tried specifying only number type to the function, but in this case ESLint is telling me "Type `undefined` is not assignable to type `number`"

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69732504/157247

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `void` you need to put `undefined`. By default, an empty return statement will return `undefined`.