# Why does void & {} not get inferred as never type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

When I use TypeScript's void type in conjunction with other types using intersection, I get different results.

```
type A = void & {} // A is void & {}
type B = void & '1' // B is never
type C = void & 1 // C is never
type D = void & string // D is never
type E = void & String // E is void & String
```

```
type A = void & {} 
type E = void & String
```

They should also be never types, right?

Comment: How would you ever have, at runtime, a value of `void & {}` or `void & String`?

Comment: Intersecting `void` with a primitive produces `never`, since you can't have a primitive that also satisfies `void`. Interestingly, that does not seem to apply to intersections of `void` with objects...

Comment: Oh yeah, and also, `void & undefined` is `undefined`, which makes a little sense but it's an exception to the void-intersected-with-primitive-rule.

Comment: I believe that `void & undefined //-> undefined` is basically the same as `number & 123 //-> 123`. Since `undefined` is assignable to `void` without a problem `const a: void = undefined // fine`. Put another way, `undefined` extends `void`.

Comment: [`void` is *weird* and not really consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69732504/2887218) so any confusing behavior can be chalked up to "‍♂️ `void`s will be `void`s ‍♂️".  If `void` were a special flavor of `undefined` then `void & {}` or `void & string` should be `never`.  But it's also a special flavor of `unknown` since you can assign `() => X` to `() => void` for all `X`, and then `void & {}` or `void & string` should probably stay as-is.  So what explains the fact that `void & string` is `never` but `void & {}` stays as-is?  "`void`s gonna `void`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{}` and `String` are both object types, and `string` and `'1'` are primitive types. You can intersect `void` with object types because object types intersect by adding properties:

```
type A = { foo: number } & { bar: string } // { foo: number, bar: string }
```

In contrast, primitive types intersect by reducing the possible set of values:

```
type B = string & 'abc' // 'abc'
```

And you can augment primitive types with new properties by intersecting them with an object type:

```
type C = string & { foo: number }
declare const c: C
c.foo // number
```

But a primitive can never be a different primitive. So intersecting two different primitive types will result in `never`

```
type D = string & number // never
type E = 1 & 2 // never
```

Lastly, `void` is a primitive type.

---

So, this all means that `void & { foo: number }` means that the primitive `void` will also have the property `foo` on it.

However, `void & string` will produce never because they are two different primitive types.

But, `void & String` is `void` with the properties of `String` because `String` is an object type (created by `new String()`).

---

This is all rather pointless, though. You can't assign anything besides `undefined` to `void`, and `undefined` can't have properties. So I'd argue that `void & Type` has no reason to exist in your codebase. And if you think you need that, I'd ask yourself why and try to refactor things to not need that.

Comment: Part of this is that `void` is *weird* and all of OPs manipulations made me say "oh, no, don't mess with `void`" when I first saw them. The `void` type is sort of like `unknown` (when it's a function return type) and sort of like `undefined` (when you start assigning things, or as function parameters). If it's `unknown`-like then it makes sense that intersecting with `{}` should probably produce `void` (or `void & {}`), but if it's `undefined`-like then intersecting with `{}` should reduce to `never` just like `undefined & {}` does.

Comment: So the fact that it stays unreduced is probably the safest thing for them to have done, but the reasoning is going to involve facing the fact that `void` is weird and inconsistent.