# Typescript infers void return type with short body arrow function but not regular arrow function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the typescript [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#void), it states that

> `void` represents the return value of functions which don’t return a value. It’s the inferred type any time a function doesn’t have any return statements, or doesn’t return any explicit value from those return statements.

It is clear what `void` does, but I don't understand why the typescript compiler doesn't seem to infer that the first code block has a return type of `void` since there is no return value, or return statement.

**Why does the first `forEach` call work? Shouldn't the first `forEach` call have the same error as the second call since there is no return value?**

```
function forEach<T>(arr: T[], callbackFn: (arg: T, idx: number) => undefined): void {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    callbackFn(arr[i], i)
  }
}

// works
forEach([1, 2, 3], (arg, idx) => {
  console.log({arg, idx})
})

// error Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
// here void is inferred
forEach([1, 2, 3], (arg, idx) => console.log({arg, idx}))
```

Comment: Feel free to post a solution if you like, I did not know that was a new feature and I was also not aware that console.log returned void.

Comment: @jcalz I never imagine that you are trying to "steal" reputation when you post answers to the same questions as me, and I often upvote your answers in those cases because they are good.

Comment: @kaya3-supportthestrike that's good, I don't like to step on toes if I can help it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In every version of TypeScript before 5.1, your first call would have also been an error:

```
function foo(cb: () => undefined) { }
foo(() => { console.log() }); // ERROR in TS5.0 and below:
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => undefined'.
// Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

But TypeScript 5.1 introduced support for [easier implicit returns for `undefined`-returning functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-1.html#easier-implicit-returns-for-undefined-returning-functions).  In particular, "if a function has no return expressions and is being passed to something expecting a function that returns `undefined`, TypeScript infers `undefined` for that function’s return type."  So that's why it works, at least if you are in a [context](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) that expects `undefined`:

```
foo(() => { console.log() }); // okay in TS5.1+
// no return statement in the function body, 
// inferred as undefined to satisfy context
```

That's the answer to the question, as asked.

---

Note that the same body will still be inferred as returning `void` and not `undefined` if you aren't in such a context, meaning that the seemingly equivalent two-step version of your first call will fail, even in TS5.1:

```
const cb = () => { console.log() };
// const cb: () => void

foo(cb); // error!
//  ~~
// Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => undefined'.
// Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

---

Also note that the second code block fails in all versions. [Arrow functions with *concise bodies*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body) like `() => expr` implicitly `return` the body expression, whereas those with *block bodies* like `() => { expr }` only return a value if there's a `return` statement in the body.

Therefore while `() => { console.log() }` doesn't return anything, `() => console.log()` returns whatever `console.log()` evaluates to.  And [according to the TS library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/28cd1fbd13b8d09259e7a7086aa258c0221c38ac/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L26433) `console.log()` returns `void`, meaning ["this function might return anything at all, so don't do anything with the return value"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#return-type-void).  (Yes, `void` is weird, see [Why is undefined assignable to void?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69728470/2887218) )

Maybe it *should* be `undefined`, since we know that's what it actually returns at runtime, but it's `void`, so that's all the compiler knows.  And if `console.log()` might evaluate to anything at all, it is rejected in places where `undefined` is required:

```
foo(() => console.log())
// -----> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUEBGAuRaCUiAvAHyLgAmApsDGFRYQN6IC+AUJyugcWSxAQBnOABsqAOlFwA5r1b4A3IgD0KxFQBOmuJsR1EAFQDKAVgkAGALTs1iRAD8nzl67dPb6gIKaZIALZUYFCIcMCIUACeAA5UiADkvKSIAG5wMBTx+kKIYHAhAIZCQjAyYAWY4hFwiNEFmgWBUFqh4VGxCUlklDR0DPESnkYxcfFpGVkwOXmFxaXllXFQNe2jPbT0mYPs3GhdiALCYpLScoQKynZwANYFkfpIJuYAjADUQ3mImlRQIJpIQigBWagWCDwiAAs4qBILAEIhMHAKJEADSIIZ0YBab4URBFchgagbBjVRBCYFTYD3QTBKgADygnBpgMQWGIeEIyUOYBE4iksnkiiGzJCWFw+3GFB2qAwmCUqnU2N0AEIho4HEMfH5QSEwhERp1OWRJZNpvk8XMyhUqstavVGj8WnrVoa+ASiX0tkNDAaxulMtlcuaiiUrYtSS74utPQNONKeEbWUc+acCPghlZM5myO43N7fSbAzMLaGFjaVr7o5sBkA)

Answer (score 2):

There is a semantic difference between these two functions. The first, with braces around the body of the arrow function, always returns the value `undefined`. The second, without braces, returns whatever value `console.log` returns.

Now you and I know that these amount to the same thing, because we know that `console.log` always returns `undefined` ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log#return_value)). But according to the Typescript compiler, `console.log` doesn't necessarily return `undefined`, it returns `void` ([source link](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/28cd1fbd13b8d09259e7a7086aa258c0221c38ac/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L26432)).

Importantly, `void` is not assignable to `undefined`, because functions which do return something other than `undefined` are assignable to types like `() => void` but not `() => undefined`. For example ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gRgDQwEy4DMAugNwBQ5A9FTCANbmiSwBmAXDABQCUqAfDABuIAJYATVNz4pBiBADoADiCW8K1WgFMkIBJwAqATyVaYAcjABXALYAjHeZiiIMMCFhwIEUQHMwcHYANmZQIDBQJmbmVmDiWqyiYFri5kzg0DC+nLwCMLHxicmSaLmy8EjKqurkQA)):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

// ok
const f: () => void = () => arr.pop();

// error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
const g: () => undefined = () => arr.pop();
```

So Typescript can statically determine that the arrow function with braces returns `undefined` (as jcalz notes, this is true [since Typescript 5.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-1.html#easier-implicit-returns-for-undefined-returning-functions)) ─ but based on what it knows, it can't determine that `console.log` also returns `undefined`, and therefore it can't determine that the arrow function without braces does too.

In your case, the solution is simple: it's more flexible to accept a callback with a return type of `void` instead of a return type of `undefined`.

Comment: @jcalz It always returns the value `undefined`, and always has; I will edit to clarify that I'm talking about the return value.

Comment: @jcalz The way I see it, the answer would be the same regardless of when the feature was added to the compiler.